# audio not playing in iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, audio

```
<audio id="test" controls="controls">
    <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="1.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

js code to play video as dom loads

```
document.getElementById('test').load();
document.getElementById('test').play();
```

working in browsers but not in iPad, what I need to set?

Answer (score 8):

According to apple's documentation, loading and playback of audio/video content has to be triggered from a user's action:

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may
>   be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and
>   autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.
>   This means the JavaScript play() and load() methods are also inactive
>   until the user initiates playback, unless the play() or load() method
>   is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play
>   button works, but an onLoad="play()" event does not.
>
> This plays the movie: `<input type="button" value="Play"
>   onClick="document.myMovie.play()">`
>
> This does nothing on iOS: `<body onLoad="document.myMovie.play()">`

Taken from here: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

Comment: Thanks for this. Rep up if you think Apple on this matter is annoying pile of shit.